# Nifi Custom Processor errors with a "ControllerService found was not a WebSocket ControllerService but a com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75"

Tags: websocket, customization, apache-nifi, processor

*** **Update**: I have changed my approach as described in my answer to the question, due to which the original issue reported becomes moot. ***

I'm trying to develop a Nifi application that provides a WebSocket interface to Kakfa. I could not accomplish this using the standard Nifi components as I have tried below (it may not make sense but intuitively this is what I want to accomplish):

[image: Using Standard Components]

I have now created a custom Processor "ReadFromKafka" that I intend to use as shown in the image below. "ReadFromKafka" would use the same implementation as the standard "PutWebSocket" component but would read messages from a Kafka Topic and send as response to the WebSocket client.

[image]

I have provided a code snippet of the implementation below:

```
@SystemResourceConsideration(resource = SystemResource.MEMORY)
public class ReadFromKafka extends AbstractProcessor {


    public static final PropertyDescriptor PROP_WS_SESSION_ID = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("websocket-session-id")
            .displayName("WebSocket Session Id")
            .description("A NiFi Expression to retrieve the session id. If not specified, a message will be " +
                    "sent to all connected WebSocket peers for the WebSocket controller service endpoint.")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_BLANK_VALIDATOR)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .defaultValue("${" + ATTR_WS_SESSION_ID + "}")
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ID = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("websocket-controller-service-id")
            .displayName("WebSocket ControllerService Id")
            .description("A NiFi Expression to retrieve the id of a WebSocket ControllerService.")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_BLANK_VALIDATOR)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .defaultValue("${" + ATTR_WS_CS_ID + "}")
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("websocket-endpoint-id")
            .displayName("WebSocket Endpoint Id")
            .description("A NiFi Expression to retrieve the endpoint id of a WebSocket ControllerService.")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_BLANK_VALIDATOR)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .defaultValue("${" + ATTR_WS_ENDPOINT_ID + "}")
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor PROP_WS_MESSAGE_TYPE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("websocket-message-type")
            .displayName("WebSocket Message Type")
            .description("The type of message content: TEXT or BINARY")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_BLANK_VALIDATOR)
            .defaultValue(WebSocketMessage.Type.TEXT.toString())
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .build();

    public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("success")
            .description("FlowFiles that are sent successfully to the destination are transferred to this relationship.")
            .build();
    public static final Relationship REL_FAILURE = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("failure")
            .description("FlowFiles that failed to send to the destination are transferred to this relationship.")
            .build();

    private static final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;
    private static final Set<Relationship> relationships;

    static{
        final List<PropertyDescriptor> innerDescriptorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        innerDescriptorsList.add(PROP_WS_SESSION_ID);
        innerDescriptorsList.add(PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ID);
        innerDescriptorsList.add(PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        innerDescriptorsList.add(PROP_WS_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(innerDescriptorsList);

        final Set<Relationship> innerRelationshipsSet = new HashSet<>();
        innerRelationshipsSet.add(REL_SUCCESS);
        innerRelationshipsSet.add(REL_FAILURE);
        relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(innerRelationshipsSet);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession processSession) throws ProcessException {
        final FlowFile flowfile = processSession.get();
        if (flowfile == null) {
            return;
        }

        final String sessionId = context.getProperty(PROP_WS_SESSION_ID)
                .evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowfile).getValue();
        final String webSocketServiceId = context.getProperty(PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ID)
                .evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowfile).getValue();
        final String webSocketServiceEndpoint = context.getProperty(PROP_WS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_ENDPOINT)
                .evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowfile).getValue();
        final String messageTypeStr = context.getProperty(PROP_WS_MESSAGE_TYPE)
                .evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowfile).getValue();
        final WebSocketMessage.Type messageType = WebSocketMessage.Type.valueOf(messageTypeStr);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionId)) {
            getLogger().debug("Specific SessionID not specified. Message will be broadcast to all connected clients.");
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(webSocketServiceId)
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(webSocketServiceEndpoint)) {
            transferToFailure(processSession, flowfile, "Required WebSocket attribute was not found.");
            return;
        }

        final ControllerService controllerService = context.getControllerServiceLookup().getControllerService(webSocketServiceId);
        if (controllerService == null) {
            getLogger().debug("ControllerService is NULL");
            transferToFailure(processSession, flowfile, "WebSocket ControllerService was not found.");
            return;
        } else if (!(controllerService instanceof WebSocketService)) {
            getLogger().debug("ControllerService is not instance of WebSocketService");
            transferToFailure(processSession, flowfile, "The ControllerService found was not a WebSocket ControllerService but a "
                    + controllerService.getClass().getName());
            return;
        }

        ...

            processSession.getProvenanceReporter().send(updatedFlowFile, transitUri.get(), transmissionMillis);

            processSession.transfer(updatedFlowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
            processSession.commit();

        } catch (WebSocketConfigurationException|IllegalStateException|IOException e) {
            // WebSocketConfigurationException: If the corresponding WebSocketGatewayProcessor has been stopped.
            // IllegalStateException: Session is already closed or not found.
            // IOException: other IO error.
            getLogger().error("Failed to send message via WebSocket due to " + e, e);
            transferToFailure(processSession, flowfile, e.toString());
        }

    }

    private FlowFile transferToFailure(final ProcessSession processSession, FlowFile flowfile, final String value) {
        flowfile = processSession.putAttribute(flowfile, ATTR_WS_FAILURE_DETAIL, value);
        processSession.transfer(flowfile, REL_FAILURE);
        return flowfile;
    }
}
```

I have deployed the custom processor and when I connect to it using the Chrome "Simple Web Socket Client" I can see the following message in the logs:

> ControllerService found was not a WebSocket ControllerService but a com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75

I'm using the exact same code as in PutWebSocket and can't figure out why it would behave any different when I use my custom Processor. I have configured "JettyWebSocketServer" as the ControllerService under "ListenWebSocket" as shown in the image below.
[image]

Additional exception details seen in the log are provided below:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75 cannot be cast to class org.apache.nifi.websocket.WebSocketService (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75 is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.nifi.nar.InstanceClassLoader @35c646b5; org.apache.nifi.websocket.WebSocketService is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader @361abd01)

Comment: I'm trying to pick this back up - the underlying issue seems to be the below exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75 cannot be cast to class org.apache.nifi.websocket.WebSocketService (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75 is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.nifi.nar.InstanceClassLoader @35c646b5; org.apache.nifi.websocket.WebSocketService is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader @361abd01)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying my flow to utilize out-of-box ListenWebSocket, PutWebSocket Processors, and a custom "FetchFromKafka" Processor that is a modified version of [ConsumeKafkaRecord](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/d6efc6958536dc2d0bc00de74ecd172e01571aef/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-kafka-bundle/nifi-kafka-2-6-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/kafka/pubsub/ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6.java). With this I'm able to provide a WebSocket interface to Kafka. I have provided a screenshot of the updated flow below. More work needs to be done with the custom Processor to support multiple sessions.

[image]